# Opencv exception fillconvexppoly

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to port a code from python to c++. I need to paint a part of an image (polygon) with black color.

In python, I had the list of points and then I call to fillconvexpolygon to do that.
I tried the same in c++ but I get this exception:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (points.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0) in fillConvexPoly, file /home/user/template_matching/repositories/opencv/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp, line 2017
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/user/template_matching/repositories/opencv/modules/core/src/drawing.cpp:2017: error: (-215) points.checkVector(2, CV_32S) >= 0 in function fillConvexPoly
```

I am able to paint lines on the image and I have points in the list of points used as polygon contour:

```
drawMatches(img_object, TSMART_BANKNOTE[i].kp, img_orig, BankNote_t.kp,
            good, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
            vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
 line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), 
                       scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), 
                                                  Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);  //Left side

 line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0),
                       scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), 
                                                  Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);  //right side

 line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), 
                       scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0),
                                                  Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);    //Down line

 line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0),
                       scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0),
                                                  Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);       //Up line

    vector<Point2f> pt;
pt.push_back(Point2f(scene_corners[0].x + img_object.cols, 
                       scene_corners[1].y));

pt.push_back(Point2f(scene_corners[2].x + img_object.cols, 
                       scene_corners[3].y));

pt.push_back(Point2f(scene_corners[1].x + img_object.cols, 
                       scene_corners[2].y));

pt.push_back(Point2f(scene_corners[3].x + img_object.cols, 
                       scene_corners[0].y));
std::cout << "PT POINTS: " << pt.size() <<"\r\n";

    //fillConvexPoly(img_matches, pt, pt.size(), Scalar(1,1,1), 16, 0);

     fillConvexPoly(img_matches, pt, cv::Scalar(255), 16, 0);
    //-- Show detected matches
std::cout <<"H5\r\n"; 
imshow( "Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);
    waitKey(0);
```

In documentation I found a fillconvexpoly function which receives size of vector. Mine seems not to accept that. I am using opencv 2.4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception says it was checking for CV_32S type(signed integer), where your points are of float type.

Replace your

```
std::vector<cv::Point2f> pt;
```

with

```
std::vector<cv::Point2i> pt;
```

Comment: Thank you!. That got it working. Is there a way to use float points instead of integer?

Comment: Not really. Remember that pixels are inherently integers. I'd not expect even the newest openCV to handle the float type. Theoretically you could make your own overload of drawPoly function that takes float points, does approximation/antialiasing and draws polygons that define more than one pixel per key point, but it will take some work and consume a lot more resources than simple drawing of polygon.